# HAXM doesn't support nested virtual machine in AWS

Tags: android, android-studio, amazon-workspaces

I'm using AWS with Windows Server 2016 OS, Android Studio 3.4.2, Java 8. When I tried to create new AVD it shows HAXM doesn't support nested virtual machine. I tried installing BlueStacks and genemotion but both failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't run it on AWS.  AWS is already a virtual machine.  You can't run a virtual machine on a virtual machine-  the CPU architecture doesn't support it.  Run the emulator locally instead.  If you're trying to do this for testing purposes, I'd look into CI platforms that already have all of this solved for you rather than rolling your own.